# Margin provided for labels in Xaml is not picking up in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to push the labels `FullName, Status, CurrenDate` from top to `10px` in the row displaying in Xamarin Forms ? I have tried with `Margin:"10,0,0,0"`, but the margin is not working for me. I would like to set the alignment via `xaml` and not via code.

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#584961">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <image:CircleImage x:Name="PlayerPic" Source="{Binding PlayerImage, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
                            <Label Text="{Binding SoccerStatus}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="3">
                            <Label Text="{Binding CurrentDate}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: `Margin:"10,0,0,0"`, it starts from left side you might need to give `Margin:"10,10,0,0"` if you want top margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins and Padding in Forms are of type [Thickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding#specifying-a-thickness).

> defined by four distinct values that are applied to the left, top,
>   right, and bottom sides of the element.

- 10,0,0,0 specifies a left margin of 10
- 0,10,0,0 specifies a top
  margin of 10